# What value does the [save] tag provide on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I was working on eliminating the [close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/close) tag and came across the [save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/save) tag, which has over 3,000 questions.  The top asker has amassed almost 150 upvotes from just one question tagged [save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/save), and the top answerer over 300 upvotes from one such question, both of which are startling.

1. Does the tag provide any value? *In my opinion, it does not.*
2. Is it appropriate to request that it be burninated?  *The volume of questions tagged [save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/save) is big enough that I decline to do it manually; it should be burninated by the Stack Exchange team using tools for the job.*

---

Given the comments, here's a short list of tags of dubious merit.  If you have other stellar examples, please add them to the list:

- [stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stop)
- [halt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/halt)
- [quit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quit)
- [hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hide)
- [slideup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slideup)
- [detect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/detect)
- [scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrolling) (almost 4,000 questions, but the 'top users' list mostly meets [Bill the Lizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard)'s [heuristic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213446/what-value-does-the-save-tag-provide-on-stack-overflow#comment687299_213446))
- [bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bus)

Comment: 1. No, 2. Yes, imo

Comment: "The top asker has asked almost 150 questions tagged save..." Unless I'm missing something, they've only asked one question, which has a score of almost 150.

Comment: OK; I wasn't reading carefully enough...I'll remove that.

Comment: If you hover over the tag on SO, the pop-up shows that it has 10 followers (although I can't imagine why).

Comment: Thanks @BilltheLizard; I've updated the question to cover both your (very valid) points.  Should I worry about the [tag:stop] tag that I've also just come across?  In this question or in a separate one.  Probably a separate one, for another time...

Comment: Don't forget [tag:halt] and [tag:maybe]! Yes, those are real tags.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The `stop` tag doesn't look very useful either. My very rough rule of thumb is to look at the [Top Users](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/stop/topusers) list. If I see mostly 1s in the "answers provided" and "questions asked" column, it's a good sign that nobody is really using the tag for anything.

Comment: @TravisJ `halt` looks pretty useless, but `maybe` looks like a Haskell thing (and maybe a functional programming thing in general).

Comment: @BilltheLizard: that sounds like a reasonable heuristic.

Comment: @BilltheLizard - Okay, I will give you back maybe :) Anyway, I was just throwing those out there since they were semi synonyms of stop and save.

Comment: @Lance Roberts Why did you create [meta-tag:save] on Meta? :)

Comment: I've removed [tag:save] from this question; it will eventually vanish from the site (and leads nowhere if followed now).

Comment: @AzizShaikh, it was a joke.

Comment: @LanceRoberts sure, thats why the smiley at the end of my comment

Comment: What is @BilltheLizard's heuristic? You link to a comment which no longer exists.

Comment: @TRiG: The [comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213446/what-value-does-the-save-tag-provide-on-stack-overflow#comment687299_213446) popped up OK for me, but to cover the bases, it said: _My very rough rule of thumb is to look at the [Top Users](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/stop/topusers) list [for the tag]. If I see mostly 1s in the "answers provided" and "questions asked" column, it's a good sign that nobody is really using the tag for anything._  The 'Top Users' URL is `http://stackoverflow.com/tags/<tagname>/topusers` (where you don't use the angle brackets, of course).

Comment: I'd like to resurrect this request if possible because I think that it has merit. Suggested title: `This tag cannot be [save]d`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have heard that in days of old, when cards were punched people did strange with the writings on the decks of cards.

Most commonly, people would draw diagonal lines across the punch cards known as [striping](http://punchcardreader.com/striping.html) (thats one 'p', not two).

[image: striped punch cards]

(from http://punchcardreader.com/striping.html )

If you look carefully at that deck, you will see also some text on the top.  That text could be the name of the program, or the language that it was written in.

Long gone are the days of FORTRAN, and COBOL, and PL/I... and other languages where the name was typed in all caps.  Their punch cards have been since used as bookmarks or otherwise recycled.

But there was some programmer who came up with an ingenious programming language.  The primary merit of the language was the likelihood that you wouldn't accidentally throw out the deck when you found it.  Why?  Because this language was named "save".  When one found a deck marked with this language, it wasn't cast out, but rather set aside.

### For the sake of this old, nearly forgotten language except for the occasional artifact found in a retiree's desk, save the [save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/save) tag!

<sup>I kind of doubt any questions about save are actually asked... but there *are* 111 questions in [jcl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jcl)... so maybe...</sup>

Comment: Amusing.  If there is ever a question about the Save language, we can resuscitate the tag; until then, I think it would be better eliminated.

Comment: Can you point to the relevant Wikipedia page?

Comment: @JanDvorak I honestly suspect it never got out too far to even be a blip on someone's radar.  Its an anecdote that I heard decades ago from a grad student who heard it from some professor who used it at some other university... So I got it nth hand.

Comment: Maybe after cleanup using `save-language` and check what it's is use.

Comment: What's your point about JCL? Countless millions of lines of JCL are processed daily. What's the Long gone stuff about? A relative dearth of questions on SO does not mean something is gone.

Comment: Given that ANSYS greets the user with a FORTRAN command prompt to this day, I'd say that FORTRAN is **nowhere near** being gone.

Answer (score 9):

More to the fire:

- [del](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/del) can be whatever, the key on the keyboard or some python function
- [elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elements) almost any programing language has this
- [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array) arrays is present in almost any language, and apart of all being arrays, their representation and functions are different, the specific languages tags will be more helpful
- [detect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/detect) no specific to programing
- [capslock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/capslock) ""
- [numlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numlock)  ""
- [keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keyboard) ""
- [buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buttons) ""

Answer (score -6):

[save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/save) could be nominated as a synonym for [file-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-system).

**About** *save*:

> To store (data) in a computer or on a storage device.

**About** *file-system*:

> In computing, a file system (or filesystem) is a type of data store
>   which can be used to store, retrieve and update a set of files. The
>   term refers to either the abstract data structures used to define
>   files, or the actual software or firmware components that implement
>   the abstract ideas.

Comment: I disagree. A filesystem is fundamentally different from "how to save information to HDD"

Comment: And "how to save information to the database"

Comment: we save our knowledge by dumping it to SO here...