# The [write] and [writing] tags have been burninated

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I recently came across the tag [write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/write) being used, and upon checking it out I noticed it had no description, and only few questions (65 as of time of writing). While adding nothing to the post.

> *Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?*

No, the tag is not unambiguous and doesn't say much about the contents of the question. It is used in different contexts including:

- writing to files (txt, pdf etc)
- writing to CLI
- commands called 'Write'

> *Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?*

In most cases the tag does seem to be used in combination with writing to a file from a given programming language.

> *Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?*

Definitely not. Just from seeing the tag you have no clue what the poster wants. What does poster want to write to? A file, variable, memory address, book, poem? For most writing operations there are already specific tags in place such as [streamwriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/streamwriter) [fwrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fwrite) [filewriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filewriter) [console.writeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/console.writeline) that would give way more information

> *Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?*

I don't think so, although *most* seem to be about file writing it is also common in programming for just "write" to mean writing to memory, lists/dictionary's (or other variables) or console outputs.

Alternatively there is also the (still ambiguous) [writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/writing) (327 questions), so maybe a merge or synonym works better.

Comment: Since there is no `read` tag, there shouldn't be a `write` tag either.

Comment: There is [tag:read-write] though, but that is more about file *accessibility* rather than file operation

Comment: We also have [tag:file-writing], which appears to be about writing files in general. Plenty of tags about writing files.

Comment: Why don't we just make [tag:write] a synonym of [tag:read-write]? @Remy - I think [tag:file-writing] needs to be a synonym of this tag too. That said, the tag itself is somewhat problematic, even [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read/write) has reservations on how unambigous it is. Which leads us to a question - should a formal burnination procedure be started for it as well?

Comment: Stumbled upon this tag today, `[write]` has 288 questions, `[writing]` 352 and `[read-write]` 564. IMO these 3 tags are meta-tags and don't really help specifying a question. So they should be trashed..

Comment: We should remove both [tag:write] and [tag:writing] at the same time.

Comment: @Dharman that should be an answer so we can vote on it.  Can we merge `write` into `writing` and then burn just one?

Comment: We probably could, but it might be easier to do a dual burn for the sake of tracking and whatnot. I always thought burns were single-tag only though, not sure if there's more steps or something if we burn several at once. Doesn't really matter anyway. If we don't do writing now, we'll do that next

Comment: What tag should we use instead for questions about the `write` syscall?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica do you have a specific language/OS in mind? If the call doesn't have a more distinctive name than `write` (APIs usually have dozens of these with slightly different names) that give direct hits in search, then creating a language specific tag for the function is the best choice e.g.: [`write-unix`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)

Comment: @bad_coder In C, it really is just called `write`.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I know what it's called in C. Depending how well a tag is organized you could combo it with a language tag, like `c`+ `write`, but `write` is too general an operation and ends up working like a magnet for off-topic and erroneous tagging (anything vaguely about writing is likely to be tagged with `write` - see `writing` that's also being considered for burnination). In such cases separating it is better [see `variadic-macros`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variadic-macros) for an example.

Comment: Then how about [tag:save]? To me it sounds like it has the same meaning as [tag:write].

Comment: @CrisLuengo [Requested elsewhere](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260214/what-value-does-the-save-tag-provide-on-stack-overflow), and far too big to do now. A 9k burnination is far too big for the current user volume, especially when there's also a substantial backlog of burninations in need of attention. We'll revisit save in the future

Comment: @CrisLuengo not to mention behemoths like [api](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255437) which at 100k Qs would take a task force to clean up.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine We will save it for later.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: Do we need a tag about the [`write(2)` system call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)?  I'd guess most of what makes it interesting is what kind of file you're writing to, most of which would also apply to `pwrite(2)` (on seekable files) or `writev(2)` (gather IO).  OTOH, it could be hard to search for questions about using it if "write" just appears in the text, since it's a common English word that appears in 2.5 million SO posts, very few of them about Linux / POSIX `write`.

Comment: Not yet mentioned but related [`read-write`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/read-write/info)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/write) and [writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/writing) have been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

Note that we're burning two tags: [writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/writing) and [write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/write). They have mostly identical question buildups, and currently don't need separate advice. Feel free to edit this answer if that changes, or edit with other observations.

- A number of questions relate to specific classes/functions for writing; examples include [streamwriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/streamwriter), [fwrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fwrite), [filewriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filewriter), [file-writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-writing) and [console.writeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/console.writeline). We don't need to create additional tags for uncovered APIs, but if they exist, using them may be appropriate.

  - The POSIX' `write()` function is present in a number of these posts; if we need a tag beyond [posix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/posix), [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux), or another contextually appropriate tag, [unistd.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unistd.h) is the better name for a tag. That tag does not currently exist, and it's somewhat undecided whether such a tag is needed in the first place.
  - In most cases, however, a simple language tag will suffice.

## Progress:

The [writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/writing) and [write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/write) tags are in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with these tags, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove these tags (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=write+writing),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted semi-automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwriting%5D+or+%5Bwrite%5D+closed%3Ano&searchOn=1)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwrite%5D+or+%5Bwriting%5D+closed%3Ayes&searchOn=1)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwriting%5D+or+%5Bwrite%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano&searchOn=1)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwrite%5D+or+%5Bwriting%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano&searchOn=1)

## Track the progress of burnination

- [Burnination coordination chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244740/burnination-hq)
- [Progress tracker](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=399366) (includes both tags)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/write) and/or [writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/writing) tags, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance". (Edits, specially re-tags, are best left to users with [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/write) and/or [writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/writing) tags—just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/write) and/or [writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/writing) tags should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove these tags from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: Are duplicates also deleted? I.e. can I dupe hammer questions but leave the tag? And are questions deleted regardless if they have positivley scored answers

Comment: Yes to all three questions. Exceptions always apply, and that's assessed on a per-case basis when deletion is considered.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, we should eliminate the [write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/write) tag.  It provides no useful information beyond the more specific tags indicating where or how one is writing.

Comment: The tag usage says it's supposed to be about the [POSIX `write(int fd, void *buf, size_t len)` system call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html), and has said that since a month after tag creation in Oct 2020 (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64310036/revisions), surprisingly *after* this meta question was posted.  I guess it got untagged at the time and then re-created, hence lack of mention of that meaning in the question and comments?  That's not something we really need a tag for anyway, and will get mis-tagged as a common English word, so +1 it doesn't add information.

Comment: @PeterCordes - perhaps `posix-write` would be a better name for such a tag?

Comment: Wouldn't that kinda be covered by a general POSIX tag? Like [tag:posix] or [tag:linux], depending on the context

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine: I'd tend to agree; `write` itself is fairly simple, what makes it interesting is what kind of file descriptor you're reading/writing (e.g. a TTY, or one opened with O_APPEND so writes go to the end even after lseek).  Perhaps a better tag would cover POSIX I/O with `unistd.h` functions in general, like `read` and `write`.  The one argument I could see for having a tag like `posix-write` is that if you do have a question specific to it (e.g. what happens if length is past the end of a page in `buf`, or size limits), it's hard to search because 2.5M questions have `write`

Answer (score 16):

Yes, we should eliminate the [writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/writing) tag.  It is essentially the same thing as [write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/write).  It provides no useful information beyond the more specific tags indicating where or how one is writing.

Comment: Did you mean to double-post here?

Comment: @NickODell It's a form of poll; one is for showing support for burning [writing], the other for burning [write]. If there's no opposition, we're taking out both. Could definitely  be clearer, though

Comment: "Can you be an expert in *writing*?" Yes, but not on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Because both tags summed have under 1k Qs I wouldn't mind burninating them together. Above that (say 1k or 1.5k) I do think it's better to burninante separately.

Comment: @richardec based on the lengthy posts written by some of our esteemed moderators, I think you *can* be an expert in writing on SO. ;)

Comment: Hah, I guess you're *write*! But then it's a meta tag. ;)