# Is there a way to separate questions for which all answers are unaccepted from questions in which the OP didn't test the answers?

Tags: discussion, questions, custom-filter

Looking for questions to answer, I browse through mainly three types of questions:

1. questions with no answer.
2. questions with unaccepted answer(s) which seems like the OP didn't find the time to check the answer(s) or to mark one of them as accepted.
3. questions with unaccepted answer(s) which the OP commented on the answer(s) to explain why they don't provide the requested output within the required limitations.

While types 1 and 3 are intersecting to answer, type 2 has higher probability to be a waste of time.

The question is whether it is possible to identify case 3 question using the filter?

Do you think it would be helpful to allow the OP to **mark unaccepted answers** In a way that would mark the question as one that all of its current answers are unaccepted by the OP?

Regarding some of the comments and answers here, I understand the importance of maintaining a knowledge base, and that this is the main goal here.

Nevertheless, the way I see it, I answer questions not just for the sake of maintaining a knowledge base, but also to help people solve their tech problems. The acceptance tells me that this person does not need help any more, and I can focus on other questions...

Am I way off here? (from the answers it seems so)

Comment: Marking acceptance is at best *slightly* misleading, so I'm not really sure why you want to pay any attention to the presence or lack of presence of it.

Comment: eh, have you tried clairvoyance? Joking aside, such a query would be hard to formalize given that there is a myriad of ways the OP could comment that the answer wasn't helpful to them. A more reasonable query would be to look for questions with answers, no accept mark and with comments by the OP. It's unlikely that even *that* is possible via search, SEDE's your friend here.

Comment: Does it need for the OP to comment on *all* answers or only *any* answer? How about the case if the OP was interested in knowing the answer back then (thus, comments on old answers), but has abandoned it (no comments on new answers)? Anyway, current filter is impossible, and acceptance is not mandatory because it's only for the OP, not the community.

Comment: Point 2. would happen much less if mods wouldn't fight against educating users about the features of the site https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418169/rule-proposal-comments-asking-for-accepts-and-votes-shall-no-longer-be-allowed

Comment: @AndrewT. , all answers must be unaccepted for the mark of "unaccepted answer" to be shown

Comment: Trying to optimise for picky OPs doesn't seem particularly constructive, to be honest. The most impactful Q&A involve the OP only very little, because they involve *so many other people* to whom the Q&A is useful.

Comment: I have "mixed feelings" about your "*... has higher probability to be a waste of time.*". It depends on the "Age" and the Score of the Qt, but yep indeed if "recent" Qt + Score already <0, then answering it will probably be a "*waste of time*" (because probably roomba'd 30 days later), but otherwise posting an Answer will always be useful for the Community, and not only for your Rep...

Comment: Editor's note: [meta-tag:unaccepted-answer] is for a situation where the OP changes the accept mark from one answer to another.

Comment: *"Am I way off here?"* - maybe, if you think that Stack Overflow is about helping individuals. That is certainly how a subset of the userbase operates and if it aids the greater good anyway there is no reason to stop them. But don't expect site tooling to aid you in that fashion, because it is the wrong focus. Help the many, not the individual. Searching for questions with zero or only downvoted answers is so much more productive, IMO.

Answer (score 22):

The truth is that we don't really care what the question asker thinks. Their job is to ask a clear, answerable and interesting question. We offer them a way to mark one of the answers as accepted, but it doesn't mean that it's the best or the only solution to the question.

If you can provide a unique and useful answer then do so regardless of whether the question has an accepted answer or not.

Comment: First time I've heard a mod use the term "interesting" to describe an on-topic question.  Really, that's the only close reason we need.  "Not clear, answerable, and/or interesting."

Comment: @RobertHarvey Interesting as in not downvote-worthy

Comment: **Even if we did** "really care what the question asker thinks" - if the asker hasn't come back to edit the question, comment on other answers to explain the issue, etc. then *why would that same asker be expected to come back at all?* The goal seems to be to try to find questions that are worthwhile answering, where the asker cares about getting an answer and simply hasn't been satisfied yet. Fully engaged askers *have a system for that already*: bounties.

Answer (score 10):

> Do you think it would be helpful to allow the OP to mark **unaccepted** answers In a way that would mark the question as one that all of its current answers are unaccepted by the OP?

Absolutely ***not*** helpful.

Questions and their answers are *for everybody*. The question asker should ***not*** have much of a say in what is "the best" answer. They can vote like anybody else, of course. The acceptance is already a bad indicator in many cases. In most others, it does not bring useful information that cannot be understood by looking at the score.

If anything, I would argue that acceptance is an anti-pattern that does measurably more harm than good. It distracts from the true purpose - maintaining a knowledge base where solutions can apply in different situations.

Comment: I understand your argument, but the way I see it, I answer questions not just for the sake of maintaining a knowledge base, but also to help people solve their tech problems. The acceptance tells me that this person does not need help any more, and I can focus on other questions...

Comment: "*The acceptance tells me that this person does not need help any more*" which is exactly the type of distraction I was talking about. If somebody asked a question years ago and accepted an answer, yet there is a better solution (be it newer one or just one that hasn't been mentioned so far) then *everybody* would benefit from that being out in the open. Despite the question asker having already accepted something.

Comment: @nimrodserok There are tons of people like me who *use the knowledge base to solve their tech problems*. Spreading the answering effort across countless niche answers is likely (and I use that soft wording only because digging up hard numbers would be difficult) to help much, much less people overall.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, I understand that, but maybe now more than before. Thank you

Comment: Absolutely. It becomes more and more clear to me that "accepted answers" were a mistake. They make it easier to view the site (wrongly) as a discussion forum, and reward people who are good at reading the minds of those who ask low-quality questions.

Answer (score 6):

> questions with unaccepted answer(s) which the OP commented on the answer(s) to explain why they don't provide the requested output within the required limitations.

Such a heuristic would be unreasonably complex to execute other than manually. There is an unbounded number of ways someone can say the answer does not work for them or is otherwise lacking. You are better off either laxing the requirement down to *any* comment by the question author *or* defining a set of common keywords and phrases used in such situations (f.e., "does not work").

The latter option is left as an exercise for the reader, but here is a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1601142/questions-with-no-accepted-answers-and-comments-by-the-op-on-an-answer) for the former, laxed case (limited to 10K posts at a time, as querying comments is quite expensive due to the sheer number of them on Stack Overflow). Please note that SEDE is updated once a week, so it will return the more false positives the closer it gets to next Sunday.

> Do you think it would be helpful to allow the OP to mark unaccepted answers

No, not in the slightest. On Stack Overflow, we are trying to build a [repository of knowledge](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for every question about programming, not the best free help desk in the world. The accept checkmark is an unfortunate relic of support forums and is largely meaningless to us.

Questions are never *solved* (which is what the accept mark is known to imply) around here because there is always a chance a better answer is posted (or a change in technology happens that renders existing answers obsolete/outdated). This makes Q&As valuable in the long run, not once, here and now, as on forums of old.

> I answer questions not just for the sake of maintaining a knowledge base, but also to help people solve their tech problems

That's ok, feel free to use any heuristic you want — we are all volunteers here, and so each is free to spend their effort however they please. Just don't forget about the long-term value when trying to help. If the question has been asked before — *do not* answer it, find a duplicate and vote/flag to close as such. If it is unclear — *do not* guess, close as "needs details". If it is poll-style — close as "opinion-based". If it covers an unreasonably vast topic — *do not* write a book, close as "too broad". The list goes on.